# Error Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, plesk

I get the error "Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist" from plesk when I try to create a new database user, the created user does not show up anywhere but the name is still reserved, and it does not allow me to access the database.

**edit:**
I was unable to login to phpMyAdmin to this webserver, so instead I managed to login to it through a different domain, and it tells me a notice: Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.90 differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.49. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

**edit:**
manually installed phpmyadmin
then manually installed libmcrypt (which is an accomplishment with my cruddy sever skills :D) so that phpmyadmin works.
Then accidentally found out how to login as root via plesk (the trick is to enter webadmin without choosing any database), at least I think it's root :S
ran the sql: GRANT SELECT ON mysql.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost'; with a success message
went back to plesk to see if I can manage the sql with "my-user" and no, its still missing from the available users, but the name is still reserved...
tried to run: mysql_fix_privilege_tables –user=root –password=mypasswordobviosuly –verbose
but gave and error, and i'm still not sure how to run direct mysql commmands without using ssh (because i dont know the root password)

Comment: Could you tell us the MySQL version you're using, the way you installed it and your OS?

Comment: linux server, no idea what mysql version as i did not install it.

Comment: Thanks for that one !

i recently update php, mysql and php-mysql and got also the same problem under plesk (not being able to create users..)

well, recreated the servers table and as you said : voila !

quick and easy bay , Thank you YuriKolovsky!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the following when attempting to upgrade. Was directed to the following page:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/112290

**I ran the following from that page:**

> "Run the following command for repairing MySQL table:
>       #mysql_upgrade -T --debug-check -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql"

Comment: That link is now a 404, and the line provided, leaves the user at a mysql prompt waiting for input. Although this is an accepted answer, it's no longer valid.

Answer (score 9):

I entered mysql via pre-installed phpmyadmin as 'root' like so: 
(in plesk) home-> database servers -> webadmin. 
Then choose the "mysql" database, if the table 'servers' is missing (probably some mysql bug) then it will need to be created:
choose 'SQL' in 'phpmyadmin' to and run the following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `servers` (
`Server_name` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Host` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Db` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Username` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Password` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Port` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Socket` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`Wrapper` char(64) NOT NULL,
`Owner` char(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Server_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='MySQL Foreign Servers table';
```

so that the table at least exists... then create a new user in plesk, and viola! it works! I was able to login as the user I created after that, it seems like it was some bug with some mysql update I did not even know about.

Comment: will this have security risk?

Comment: @Rafiq no, it will not pose a security risk

Comment: I got this error, while show tables showed table servers to be there. I needed to
    DROP TABLE servers;
and then CREATE TABLE as above, and I got it to work!

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon maybe you had some sort of permission errors and by recreating it you got the permissions?

Comment: No permission errors, it's some kind of bug in MySQL and happens when you are upgrading the version, in my case from MySQL 5.5->5.7 (Ubuntu Trusty -> Xenial).

Comment: If anyone was led here by [How to Reset Your MySQL or MariDB Root Password](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password) I can confirm this works.

Answer (score 7):

This error can sometimes appear after a new installation of MySQL when the mysql table does not get created properly. Running the command...

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

from the bash prompt (not the MySQL prompt) will install the table and get things working.

After running the command above on a new installation the following command will help secure the install...

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

This will prompt you to enter a root password, remove anonymous access, limit root access to localhost only and remove the test database.

These commands are for Linux, they may not work on Windows but there are corresponding commands if you search the MySQL docs.

This is not related to the Plesk issue of the original poster but I stumbled upon this question while researching a MySQL installation problem and thought this might help save someone some time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your user does not have access to the `mysql` database. You may want to grant the `SELECT` command as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.* TO 'your-user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: how would I run this on the external server?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: How do you access your MySQL server? Do you have root access? Are you using something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: yes phpMyAdmin it is, which is not letting me access it saying there are no users :S

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Can you log in with root in phpMyAdmin? If yes, do so, and execute `GRANT SELECT ON mysql.* TO 'your-user'@'localhost';` You'd have to substitute the `your-user` bit with the username you're using in your application.

Comment: I found out that to login as root I need to manually install phpmyadmin, and I did so, but thanks to my complete inexperience with servers I can't get it to work, phpMyAdmin just throws "Cannot load mcrypt extension"

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Do you have access to the server via ssh? If so you can probably log into mysql using `mysql -u root -p` and then grant the select privileges to your user as described in my answer.

Comment: I don't seem to know the mysql root password... but I managed to login with plesk as the root user and run the above command, it returned success but did not help the situation as the user i created earlier is still missing... but its name is reserved...

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: The `GRANT` command will return successfully even if the user does not exist. By the way, did you try an empty password for root? I think that is the default one.

Comment: thanks for that tip, i will keep that in mind :P. no, empty did not work.

Comment: but now i solved the problem, what should I do with your help even though it was not the solution? should I post my own solution as the solution?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Yes, feel free to post a new answer and accepting it. I'm glad you solved the problem :)

Comment: thanks for the moral assistance, it is more appreciated than you think, as i solved it trying to find a way to run your sql :D

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: No probs :) ... You may want to post the solution as an answer, instead of as part of the question. It's an acceptable way to post solutions to own questions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `show tables` in `mysql` database identifies `servers` table exists, but yet I got the `Error Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist` error.

Listing `<data-dir>/mysql` directory revealed `servers.frm` file exists, but relative `servers.MYI` and `servers.MYD` files were missing - maybe I played a role on that!

Anyhow knowing that I'm using the server as an intermediate server in a `Daisy Chain Replication`, I got a backup from `servers.frm` file and recreated the table by running the @timo-huovinen's answer things got back to normal.

It's noteworthy that there was at least one other table (`plugin`) missing `MYI` and `MYD` files.